# Guy prepares revenge for 10 years for the murder of his daughter and wife

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this English movie a few years ago and I don't know its name.

- There's this guy whose name I don't know (hitherto referred to as "X man") in his house with his wife and daughter.
- 2 guys kill the woman and the child.
- They are caught and one of the guys (the less violent one) is killed with substances put in his blood (I don't know the name of it).
- The other one escapes but the "X man" gets him by putting something on a pistol that paralyzes him. He then tortures him with him watching everything through a mirror on top of him (with the photos of the wife and daughter so they can "watch it") and then kills him.
- He prepares the revenge for 10 years, is arrested and the police must do what the "X man" wants.
- There is a black guy who is part of the police or part of the court.
- I remember a scene in which the "X man" orders food and they arrive late, he tells them where a man is hidden and they go there to save. But as they arrived late with the food the man died because his oxygen supply ended.
- In the end he is killed because of a bomb he was planning to make explode somewhere but the bomb was in his cell.

I recall many details but I can't really remember what the title is. **What is the name of this movie?**

Comment: I think you're getting Gerard Butler mixed up with Hugh Jackman. They have similar appearances & builds, but Butler was never an X-Man (Jackman is famous for playing Wolverine).

Comment: I think OP just called him X bacause he doesn't know his name. Unless you're kidding. ;)

Comment: X man is the man whose name is unknown to me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is [Law Abiding Citizen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1197624/combined) from 2009 with Gerard Butler and Jamie Foxx:

> Clyde Shelton's family is brutally murdered. The ones responsible are caught. However, because of improper procedure, the D.A., Nick Rice only has circumstantial evidence. So he decides to get one of them to testify against the other. When Shelton learns of this, he is not happy. Ten years later, the one who was convicted is being executed but something goes wrong; his execution goes awry and he suffers. They learn that someone tampered with the machine. And the other one is found dead, killed in a gruesome manner. Rice suspects Shelton, so he has him picked up. At first, Shelton agrees to a plea agreement with Rice but changes his mind. It appears that Shelton is not done, it appears he blames the whole system and is declaring war on it going after everyone involved with his family's case. So Rice has to stop him but Shelton is way ahead of him.

Shelton murders those he holds responsible in the manners you've described and the film ends exactly as you put it. Jamie Foxx plays the prosecutor. Here's the trailer:

Comment: This is the movie that came to my mind when I read the question

Comment: Excellent movie - great answer! Beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I tried to type parts of the description on Google but I never found the name of this movie.

Comment: The law-abiding citizen, Clyde, is probably one of the best well-written characters I've ever seen. He commands the plot to his whim for basically the entire movie, confident in his skills, and easily able to outwit his adversaries.

Comment: @phyrfox ? The  plot is a giant collection of holes and Clyde's character is not credible.